# How to link_to an html anchor tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been trying to make a number of lists where after clicking each list its content gets edited. I'am using twitter bootstrap, embedded HTML in this Ruby on Rails app.

```
<div class="list-group">
    <% @statuses.each do |status| %>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><%= status.content %></a>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

Here i did not get how to get these `<%= link_to` to get connected with each `<a href=""` URL's of the `status`.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_status_path(status) %>
```

[image: Each list here should be linked to status]

Please help i m totally confused.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the entire status to actually be a link, like you did with a manual anchor tag in your example, then try:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <% @statuses.each do |status| %>
      <%= link_to status.content, edit_status_path(status), class: "list-group-item" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Also see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to.